# Venn diagram problem with three beverages liking

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

In a group of people who like beverages tea, coffee and milk, 9 people like tea, 9 people like coffee and 15 people like milk. If 5 people like tea and milk, 7 people like coffee and milk and 3 people like all three beverages. How many people like tea and coffee but not milk? The total number of people is 20.

To my understanding, there are 15 people who like milk. These 15 includes 3 that likes all the three. Since 5 likes both tea and milk, this is included with the 3 that likes all the three beverages. So, 2 likes both tea and milk only as per the Venn diagram. Similarly, 4 likes only coffee and milk. Going by this, I tried to find those that like only tea and coffee (x) which is 9-5-x under tea side (refer attached diagram). The x should be the same as 9-7-x for coffee. The equation 9-5-x=9-7-x is not solvable. I know I am wrong somewhere. Help appreciated.

Comment: The thing that is wrong is that those two numbers aren't supposed to be equal!  One is the tea only people, the other is the coffee only people. Your setup looks sound, I'm having trouble finding enough information to solve the problem

Comment: I agree with Alan in that it looks like there is not enough information (I also agree with their other statement). Was there perhaps any information on the size of the group? If you had one more piece of information, you should be able to solve for $x$.

Comment: The problem is not stated correctly or they missed some information. There are $4$ people who drink tea but not milk and there are $2$ who drink coffee but not milk. Now there could be max $2$ common people who drink both tea and coffee but not milk. So the answer can be anything between $4$ and $6$.

Comment: @Alan  There are 20 people in total. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrating the ideas already indicated by the comments:

Consider the following chart:

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
\text{Variable} & \text{Tea} & \text{Milk}  
& \text{Coffee} & \text{Value} \\
\hline 
v_1 & t & t & t & 3 \\ \hline
v_2 & t & t & f & 2 \\ \hline
v_3 & t & f & t &   \\ \hline
v_4 & t & f & f &   \\ \hline
v_5 & f & t & t & 4 \\ \hline
v_6 & f & t & f & 6 \\ \hline
v_7 & f & f & t &   \\ \hline
v_8 & f & f & f &   \\ \hline
\end{array}

From the constraints: 
$v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + v_4 = 9$. 
$v_1 + v_3 + v_5 + v_7 = 9$. 
$v_1 + v_2 + v_5 + v_6 = 15$. 
$v_1 + v_2 = 5$. 
$v_1 + v_5 = 7$. 
$v_1 = 3$.

It is required to solve for $v_3$.

From the above constraints:

- As shown in the chart, $v_1, v_2, v_5, v_6$ are now all known.
- $v_3 + v_4 = 4.$
- $v_3 + v_7 = 2.$
- Based on the added constraint that the total number of people is $20$, you have that $v_7 + v_8 = 1$ and $v_4 + v_8 = 3.$

The constraint that $v_7 + v_8 = 1$ clearly has two possibilities, that lead to two separate solutions for $v_3$.

Either $v_7 = 1 \implies v_3 = 1$ 
or $v_7 = 0 \implies v_3 = 2.$

Comment: By attached diagram, solved this way: 9 (tea circle)+6 (in milk part)+4 (coffee+milk only)+ 9-7-x (coffee part) = 20, or x=1.

Comment: @SplendidDigitalSolutions Two problems: [1] Although you are given that there are $(20)$ people, you are not given that they all drink something.  It is possible that there is 1 person who drinks nothing.  Therefore, you don't know if $$21 - x = 20 ~~\text{or} ~~21 - x = 19.$$ [2] In general, for such a problem, it is usually much easier to use a chart, with variables, as I did in my answer.  The use of a diagram leads to (potentially) convoluted analysis and confusion, such as not recognizing (for example) that $v_8$ (in my chart) might not equal $0$.